# preg_matching on facebook profile.php

Tags: php, facebook

how to grab facebook username? using preg_matching?

this is my sample code!

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/profile.php");
$username = preg_match('/<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; URL=^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $page, $matches) ? $matches[1]: '/djmardagz?_fb_noscript=1';

echo $username;
?>
```

that's my idea, but it's not working, whew anyone know how to grab facebook username?
like for example:
you visit my site, after that i got your facebook username....

so how was it done? anyone know? please share :)

Comment: the best way is to use the facebook api. [facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Comment: @Ibu: not the best, but the only legal.

Comment: "you visit my site, after that i got your facebook username" -- that doesn't sound insidious at all...

Comment: facebook ppl are not crazy to give you username from this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way to do that is if you get a referrer back to a url like :

```
facebook.com/profile.php?id=....
```

Then, you can quite easily parse the url and get more information on the user. But if you do not have that information, it's not possible to do so.

It's quite easy to then parse the url using curl and reg matching.